# Swift 5: Handling and decoding error of JSON

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, swift5

Im running a service, which when I get an error it should show me the error message that comes from the backend. So far I have done this, and it works.

However, I would like to know if it is possible to parse the back error in an enum for example, or something like that so that I would not have to call response.errors.result... But I can't understand how to do it to later obtain the string of the message that comes from the back in case of error.

On the other hand, I have a question about whether it is possible not to have the default when the optional value is nil in the service. I mean the cases where I have to perform ?? ErrorMutation(code: 10, message: "error") for example. If exist a way where i don't have to pass it a default value.

```
struct ResponseData: Codable {
    let data: Data?
    let errors: Errors?
}
```

---

```
struct Data: Codable {
    let result: Mutation?
}
```

---

```
struct Mutation: Codable {
    let id: String?
    let active: Bool?
}
```

---

```
struct Errors: Codable, Error {
    let result: [ErrorMutation]?
}
```

---

```
struct ErrorMutation: Codable, Error {
    let code: Int?
    let message: String?
}
```

---

```
final class MutationManager: Service {
    func getTDMutation() -> Observable<Result<Mutation, ErrorMutation>> {
        let mutationQuery = Bundle.main.value ?? ""
        let body = ["query": "mutation \(mutationQuery)"]
        return response(body: body)
            .map {
                try JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseData.self, from: $0) }
            .flatMap { response -> Observable<Result<Mutation, ErrorMutation>> in
                guard response.data != nil else {
                    let error = response.errors?.result.first
                    return .just(.failure(error ?? ErrorMutation(code: 10, message: "error")))
                }
                return .just(.success(response.data?.result ?? Mutation(id: "", active: false)))
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated but never name a custom struct `Data`. It can clash with Foundation `Data`

Answer (score 0):

Parsing with **Codable** you have to rewrite code **ResponseData** class and **Data** class Like This.

```
struct ResponseData: Codable {
    let dataMutation: DataMutation?
    let errors: Errors?

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case errors, dataMutation = "data"
    }
}

struct DataMutation: Codable {
    let result: Mutation?
}
```